# Remove quoted value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to remove the double-quoted in column values. for that, I am using regex_expression and replace but it doesn't remove the double-quoted can anyone please help me on this

I have value like this

"XYZ.COM "

I need to replace the above as

XYZ.COM

I tried this

```
regexp_replace(domain), '[^\w]+^.','','g')
replace(domain,'"','')
```

Note : I don't want to remove the dot from the string

Comment: `replace(domain,'"','')` should do exactly that.

Comment: I tried that also but getting the same quoted...

Comment: Then show us the **complete** code you are using because that will definitely work. See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5e2fe18b7371e979683b6cae15e1100f

Answer (score 1):

From the comments I guess that you are not really dealing with regular double quotes but with other characters (the so-called “curly quotes”).

So give the following a try:

```
replace(domain, E'"\u201C\u201D\u201E', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`trim`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html) function with extra parameter.

```
postgres=# select trim(' "' from '"XYZ.COM "');
┌─────────┐
│  btrim  │
╞═════════╡
│ XYZ.COM │
└─────────┘
(1 row)
```